# I am getting error when I am using Beanshell Sampler with script in jmeter

Tags: javascript

I am getting error when I am using Beanshell Sampler with script in jmeter  as:

ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: `//my beanshell script log.info("Example Sample");  String maVariable = vars.get( . . . '' Encountered ";" at line 8, column 22. and
WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of:`//my beanshell script log.info("Example Sample");  String maVariable = vars.get( . . . '' Encountered ";" at line 8, column 22.

and my code is

```
//my beanshell script 
log.info("Example Sample");  
String maVariable = vars.get("VARIABLE_NAME");  
if (maVariable.equals("1")      
{

 ResponseCode = 2*100 ;

ResponseMessage=  "Okey" ;

 vars.put("NAME" , "VALUE") ; 

} 

return "Beanshell wrote this message";
```

I searched for it, I think I need some plugins for this to complete. I downloaded one of it i.e. bsh-2.0b2.jar but I unable to complete my task. 
I don't no where I went wrong, If anyone have any idea please share it. Thanks In advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the ending ) on the if statement.

`if (maVariable.equals("1")`
 should be 
`if (maVariable.equals("1") )`

To verify I ran the test with 50 users looping 500 times on 2 servers.  Here is the [Load Test and the JMX File](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11658).

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks, I want to perform steps using beanshell sampler.      A. Copy the file from server to my desktop                                                    B. Read the specific string from the file. I am using Beanshell sampler for that Can you suggest how to do that ?

Comment: If you have any JMX file with same approach please share it.

Comment: yes Richard, It resolved my original question. But I am looking to copy a file from SFTP server to my desktop and read a specific string from the file .As I don't have any specififc programming background can you suggest how can I achieve it ?